# getting error "start.getDate() is not a function" when I am using this function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
                const start = body.startDate; 
                const end  =body.endDate;   
                var dayCount = 0

                while (end > start) {
                  dayCount++
                  start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1)
                }
                console.log("datedifferent"+dayCount);
```

why I am Getting error start.getDate() is not function

Comment: What is `body.startDate`?

Comment: Can you give some examples of `body.startDate`?

Comment: body is my model class reference like (async getIncidentByTime(body :EMP): Promise<any>  in my EMP model i do have field (satrtDate, and  endDate)

Answer (score 0):

```
const start = new Date(Date.parse(body.startDate)); 
const end = new Date(Date.parse(body.endDate));   
var dayCount = 0

while (end > start) {
  dayCount++
  start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1)
}
console.log("datedifferent"+dayCount);
```

Comment: in that case getting compile error "Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The variable start is not a date Object, hence you are getting that error.

Create start as a Date Object as mentioned in the answer by the user Prime.